# Janko Group and subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computer-algebra-systems, computational-algebra

I want to work with the Janko simple group $J_2$ using the computer, and if it is possible, the Janko simple group $J_4$ too. In specific, I want to take certain subgroups of it and compute their lattice subgroup. Other question is if exists accesible bibliography about those groups to read about its subgroups and others characteristics of them.

I was working in GAP, but it doesn't support the $J_2$ group, because after certain point using the commands, it breaks and doesn't do correctly the commands based on it. I'm trying to use Magma, but it doesn't have a command to obtain the subgroups of a certain group, only conjugation classes, and brings me different solutions against the (mathematically proved) solutions that GAP gives. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you find GAP and Magma are returning different results then you should report it! But on the Janko group $J_2$, $\mathtt{Subgroups}(G)$ in Magma and $\mathtt{ConjugacyClassesSubgroups}(G)$ in GAP both return a list of $146$ representatives of the comjugacy classes of subgroups with the same orders, so I don't see any evidence of a disagreement there. It is not hard to get a complete list of subgroups from the conjugacy class representatives. Just conjugate the representatives by a transversal of a normalizer.

Comment: May be the problem of different results is that the order of the group is not accesible for a common computer if you want to work for example in the normalizer's of one subgroup. I don't know, may be is that.

Comment: For example, if you call in GAP to the normalizer of a sylow subgroup of $J_2$, it returns a group of order 1. (It returns Group [()]), but that is nonses because itself is a normalizer.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. What command did you run that returned the trivial group?

Comment: M:=MathieuGroup(12); Z:=SylowSubgroup(M,3); K:=Normalizer(M,Z);   And then K is a group of order 1, but that doesn't have sense.

Comment: When I tried it, $\mathtt{K}$ was a group of order $108$. Also, it would not let me use $\mathtt{Z}$ as a variable name.

Comment: Oh, so maybe I will have to reinstall GAP. (Thanks for do it in your computer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magma

```
> S := [ s`subgroup : s in Subgroups(G) ];
> SS:= &cat[[s^t : t in Transversal(G,Normaliser(G,s))] : s in S];        
> #SS;
1104344
```

gives a list of all 1104344 subgroups of $J_2$. I am sure you can do it in a similar way in GAP by starting with $\mathtt{ConjugacyClassesSubgroups}(G)$.

I fin it unlikely that you will succeed in computing a list of all subgroups of $J_4$.

Comment: Thanks! Away from this, do you know if it's possible to enter the Thompson Group in GAP or Magma?

Comment: Yes, see http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/Th/  It has generators in both GAP and Magma format, but only for matrix representations. The smallest degree permutation representation is degree 143 127 000 which is not completely impossibly big, but you may find that  your ability to compute in the groups i limited.

Comment: I really thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In GAP (at least in principle -- my laptop did not have enough memory to store all of J2):

```
g:=SimpleGroup("J2");
u:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g);;
v:=Concatenation(List(u,Elements));;
```

You will get repeatedly (after exceeding 2GB, 4GB, etc of memory) a warning from GAP "Error, reached the pre-set memory limit". This is a safety feature to stop a computing task potentially bringing the whole computer to its knees. Simply enter

```
return;
```

to continue the calculation.